# How can I preserve the executable bit on a file that is synchronized by Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, scripts, permissions

A script I am working on is in a folder that is synchronized by Ubuntu One. Every time I edit it from another computer, it looses its executable bit and I must manually reapply `chmod +x`.

How can I avoid having to repeatedly set this?

Comment: This sounds very much like a legitimate bug. You should see if it has been filed, and - if not - file it yourself.

Comment: I'd just assumed it was a security feature, albeit an annoying one.

Comment: I was sure it was a security feature to prevent hacking of computers through Ubuntu One. Cause once you've cracked a Dropbox account with synced bin files I imagine there is very few you can't do to the synced computers. Anyway it should be a bug since it doesn't let the user choose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stefano suspected, this is [indeed a bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/385511). You can click Subscribe on the top right to have it email progress to you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Ubuntu One does not sync metadata about files (last modified time, permissions). The biggest problem is that different systems store different metadata and those that do store similar metadata store it in different ways. There is a bug report you can comment on here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/385511